# Como deixar minha lista dentro do card com tamanho responsivo!

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo, flexbox

Gostaria de deixar o conteúdo em destaque dentro do card e não sair para fora, pois quando se deixa a tela pequena eles acabam saindo.
Fiz meu site utilizando flexbox como base.

[image: Imagem do site no mobile]

```css
body {
  background-color: #F2AE2E;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif
}

body,
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.header {
  color: white;
  background-color: #323E40;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
}

.header h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.menu li {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.menu a {
  padding: 10px;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

.cl-red {
  color: red;
}

#home {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(../img/wallpaper_pizza.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 700px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#titulo {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border: 4px solid red;
  border-radius: 5%;
}

#titulo h1 {
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 0;
}

#btn {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 4px solid #D96704;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#btn a {
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#btn a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

#title {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #323E40;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
}

#produtos img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#produtos {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#produtos div {
  border: 5px ridge #BF2604;
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 1 1 150px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #323E40;
}

#produtos h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
  color: #D96704;
  padding: 6px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

#produtos h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #F2AE2E;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

#produtos ul {
  text-align: center;
}

#produtos li {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

#title-contato {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #D96704;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#informacoes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px;
}

#informacoes div {
  margin: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

#contato {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#contato img {
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

#contato h1 {
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#rodape {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #323E40;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">

  <h1>Pizza's <span class="cl-red">Sinai</span></h1>
  <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#produtos">Produtos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contato">Contato</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<section id="home">
  <div id="box-central">
    <div id="titulo">
      <h1>Pizzas Delivery pertinho de você!</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="btn">
      <a href="#produtos">Veja Mais</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="title">
  <h1>Veja os Nossos produtos!</h1>
</section>

<section id="produtos">
  <div>
    <img src="img/pizza_moda.jpg">
    <h2>Pizza a Moda</h2>
    <h3>Igredientes: </h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Apresuntado</li>
      <li>Mussarela</li>
      <li>Bacon</li>
      <li>Calabresa</li>
      <li>Cebola/Pimentao</li>
      <li>Milho e Ervilha</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="img/pizza_moda.jpg">
    <h2>Pizza de Frango</h2>
    <h3>Igredientes: </h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Mussarela</li>
      <li>Frango</li>
      <li>Catupiry</li>
      <li>Cebola</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="img/pizza_moda.jpg">
    <h2>Pizza de Calabresa</h2>
    <h3>Igredientes: </h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Mussarela</li>
      <li>Calabresa</li>
      <li>Cebola/Pimentao</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="img/pizza_moda.jpg">
    <h2>Pizza de Bacon</h2>
    <h3>Igredientes: </h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Mussarela</li>
      <li>Bacon</li>
      <li>Cebola/Pimentao</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="img/pizza_moda.jpg">
    <h2>Pizza Portuguesa</h2>
    <h3>Igredientes: </h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Apresuntado</li>
      <li>Mussarela</li>
      <li>Calabresa</li>
      <li>Ovo</li>
      <li>Cebola/Pimentao</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="informacoes">
  <div>
    <img src="https://www.redelevepizza.com.br/assets/imagens/pizza-grande-35-cm.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://www.redelevepizza.com.br/assets/imagens/pizza-acrescente-mais-sabor.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://www.redelevepizza.com.br/assets/imagens/pizza-experimente-com-refrigerante.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://www.redelevepizza.com.br/assets/imagens/pizza-massa-leve.png">
  </div>
</section>

<section id="title-contato">
  <h1>Entre em Contato</h1>
</section>

<section id="contato">
  <div>
    <img src="img/whatsapp.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>(XXX)XXXX-XXX</h1>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="novidades">

</section>

<footer id="rodape">
  <div>
    <p> © Pizza's Sinai, todos direitos reservados </p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

João, para resolver isso você precisa definir @media Rules que servem para aplicar estilos diferentes para dispositivos/tipos de mídia diferentes.

Vou deixar um exemplo aqui, mas você terá que aplicar para o site, conforme a sua necessidade:

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>The @media Rule</h1>

  <p>Resize the browser window. When the width of this document is 600 pixels or less, the background-color is "lightblue", otherwise it is "yellow".</p>
</body>
```

Para entender o funcionamento deste exemplo, abra-o em tela cheia (página toda), daí vá diminuindo a largura da tela. Quando a tela ficar com menos de 600px, a cor de fundo deverá mudar.

Para entender melhor este conceito de @media Rules, sugiro que você dê uma olhada no [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). Inclusive, este snippet que coloquei aqui, foi retirado de lá.